# Counting GF($q=8$) matrices with a certain property

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, finite-fields, matrix-rank, inclusion-exclusion

Let us denote by $\boldsymbol{v}_i$ the columns of an $m \times n$ GF($8$) matrix. The field elements are enumerated $\{0,1,2,...,q-1\}$. To define the arithmetic operations between field elements, we consider each each element as a polynomial of degree at most $2$ with GF($2$) coefficients that are its binary representation. For example, 
$$0 \leftrightarrow 0,1 \leftrightarrow 1,2 \leftrightarrow z,3 \leftrightarrow z + 1,4 \leftrightarrow {z^2},5 \leftrightarrow {z^2} + 1,6 \leftrightarrow {z^2} + z,7 \leftrightarrow {z^2} + z + 1$$

The GF($8$) operations are then carried out as addition/multiplication of polynomials, modulo an irreducible polynomial of degree $3$.

I would like to find the number of matrices with columns such that $$\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {{\alpha _i} \cdot {\boldsymbol{v}_i}}  = 0,$$ $\alpha_i \in \{0,1,2,3\}$, only if $\alpha_i$ are all zero. Note that the  set $\{0,1,2,3\}$ is a subgroup of the additive group of GF($8$). In addition, if instead we conidered $\tilde \alpha_i \in \{0,1,2,...,q-1\}$, the question reduces to determining the number of full-rank matrices, which is $\prod\limits_{i = 1}^n {\left( {{q^m} - {q^{i - 1}}} \right)}$.

Taking the concrete example $m=2, n=3$, I encountered a problem when trying to mimic the calculation of the number of full-rank matrices. For the first column, any column except the zero vector can be used. Thus, the first column can be chosen in $q^m-1$ ways. The second column cannot be chosen such that $\alpha_1 \cdot \boldsymbol{v}_1 + \alpha_2 \cdot \boldsymbol{v}_2 = 0$, or equivalently $(\alpha_1 / \alpha_2) \cdot \boldsymbol{v}_1 = \boldsymbol{v}_2$. This means that the second column can be chosen in $q^m - 8$ ways, since $| {\{ {{\alpha _1}/{\alpha _2}} \}} | = 8$ ($\alpha_2 \ne 0$). Continuing in this fashion, the $i^{\rm th}$ column can be chosen in $q^m-8^{i-1}$ ways. However, this leads to $\left( {64 - 1} \right)\left( {64 - 8} \right)\left( {64 - 64} \right) = 0$ ways in the example above, instead of the correct number which is 84,672 (found by a computer exhaustive search).

I suspect that the inclusion-exclusion principle should be used, but I am not sure how.

Comment: What exactly are the $\{0,1,2,3\}$? Do you consider them as elements of $GF(8)$ as you enumerated them? Then it is probably important to know which elements of $GF(8)$ they do correspond to, as different elements have different properties.

Comment: Basically the second column just cannot be *any* multiple of the first column. And then the third column cannot be any linear combination of the first two column. Why are there exactly 64 distinct linear combinations of the first two columns? Could it be that there are only 30 distinct combinations?

Comment: @Servaes I think the problem is that we can only use coefficients $\alpha_i$ where there are only $4$ possibilities each.

Comment: @flawr The quotients of the non-zero elements of an additive subgroup of order $4$ of $\operatorname{GF}(8)$ give all non-zero elements of $\operatorname{GF}(8)$. In your list above you are missing $1/2$ and $1/3$. The problems begin with the third vector, as then you do not take all pairs of quotients as pairs of coefficients, but only those with the same denominator.

Comment: We want to find the number of $v_3 \neq 0$ with $\alpha_1 v_1 + \alpha_2 v_2 \neq -\alpha_3 v_3 $ for all $\alpha_i $ with $(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3) \neq 0$. In the the case $\alpha_3= 0$ can be ignored, as then $\alpha_2=0$ and $ \alpha_3=0$. So we have 4 possibilities for each $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ and three possibilities for $\alpha_3$. But now we counted $v_3=0$ three times other solutions probably too. So we probably need to know the exact structure of $\{0,1,2,3\}$.

Comment: @flawr I update the question. Hope that now the exact structure is clear.

Comment: You didn't spell out why $(\alpha_1 / \alpha_2) \cdot \boldsymbol{v}_1 = \boldsymbol{v}_2$ excludes a full $8$ values for $\boldsymbol{v}_2$. This can be proved using the pigeonhole principle: If $\boldsymbol{v}_2$ is any multiple of $\boldsymbol{v}_1$, the $4^2-1=15$ admissible non-trivial linear combinations of them are also a multiple of $\boldsymbol{v}_1$; as there are only $8$ of those, at least two combinations must be the same; and then subtracting them yields a non-trivial zero combination.

Comment: The same argument doesn't hold for the third column, as there are now $4^3-1=63$ admissible non-trivial linear combinations, which is also the number of non-trivial unconstrained linear combinations of two vectors, so it's possible that $\boldsymbol{v}_3$ is a linear combination of $\boldsymbol{v}_1$ and $\boldsymbol{v}_2$ yet the admissible non-trivial linear combinations are all zero.

Note that the number $84672$ that you found is $24(64-1)(64-8)$, so it's possible that each combination of $\boldsymbol{v}_1$ and $\boldsymbol{v}_2$ allows for $24$ values of $\boldsymbol{v}_3$.

Comment: @joriki It seems to me that the difficulty is due to the structure of subgroups of 4 elements, which are not necessarily multiples of each other. When using the same logic for $\hat \alpha_i \in \{0,1\}$, $\prod\limits_{i = 1}^n {\left( {{q^m} - {2^{i - 1}}} \right)}$ seems to be correct.